# How can I change the definition of class methods after pickling

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pickle, dill

I am writing a class that does some data processing. I initiated the class and did some processing then pickled the results.
the problem is that I added new methods to the class and loaded the pickled objects but I couldn't apply the new methods to the unpickled ones.

For example, This is my class

```
class Play(ABC):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    
  @abstractmethod
  def method(self):
    pass

class M(Play):

  def __init__(self, data):
    super().__init__(data)

  def method(self):
    self.corr = np.corrcoef(self.data)
```

I did some processing

```
mat = np.random.rand(102, 641)
s = M(mat)
s.method()
```

and pickled them using dill

```
def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output:  
        dill.dump(obj, output, dill.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
save_object(s, 'file.pkl')
```

then, I added new methods to the class and unpickled the file to apply those methods but I couldn't

```
class Play(ABC):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    
  @abstractmethod
  def method(self):
    pass

class M(Play):

  def __init__(self, data):
    super().__init__(data)

  def method(self):
    self.corr = np.corrcoef(self.data)
  
  def new(self):
    # pass
    self.q = self.corr.shape
def load_object(filename):
  with open(filename, 'rb') as input:
    obj = dill.load(input)
    return obj
```

```
obj = load_object('file.pkl')
obj.new()
```

and I get this result

> AttributeError: 'M' object has no attribute 'new'

How can I fix that?

Comment: It's because `dill` saved the original class definition.

Comment: why don't you just load file first, then define/add new methods?

Comment: @LeiYang how can I do so?

Comment: in my opinion, data is just data, don't mix with the classes' states. pikle only promise you get same thing you write. that's enough. others is totally business logic and design patterns. you can state your final goal and let's come up with other solutions.

Comment: I agree with you.
my goal is to save the current version of the data for further processing and avoiding starting from scratch as it is very expensive computationally.
I can think about writing the whole class first then applying it but I think It is not elegant @LeiYang

Comment: the design should depend on how the data looks like. you have a lot of options such as csv, json, even database.

Comment: @ahmed Another possible option for you could be to use pytorch's `nn.Module` as the parent class that you inherit from and then just extend the class to write your own. The benefit is, you could use the natively available statedict saving functionality to save your class and it's data together. see here: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html. If you would like some demo class on this one and how to save it, let me know and I will share an example here.

Comment: @CypherX this is a good solution, if you can share an example it would be very helpful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative for you is to use [`joblib`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/compressors_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-compressors-comparison-py) library. I will also encourage you to check the documentation for `joblib` shared in the **References** section below.

```py
joblib.dump(obj, "filename.joblib")    ## Saving object to a file
obj = joblib.load("filename.joblib")   ## Loading object from a file
```

### Save and Load your object: 1st time

```py
class Foo(object):
    x = 1

    def bar(self, y):
        return y + self.x

f1 = Foo()

def checkFoo(foo: Foo):
    print(f'version: {foo.version}')

## save your object
>>> version = '0.0.1'
>>> f1.version = version
>>> checkFoo(f1)
'0.0.1'
>>> joblib.dump(f1, f'object_store_v{version}.joblib')
['object_store_v0.0.1.joblib']

## load saved object (latest version)
>>> version = '0.0.1'
>>> f2 = joblib.load(f'object_store_v{version}.joblib')
>>> checkFoo(f2)
'0.0.1'
```

### Save and Load your object: 2nd time (*after modification*)

```py
## Modify object and save new version
>>> version = '0.0.2'
>>> f2.version = version
>>> checkFoo(f2)
'0.0.2'
>>> joblib.dump(f2, f'object_store_v{version}.joblib')
['object_store_v0.0.2.joblib']

## load saved object (latest version)
>>> version = '0.0.2'
>>> f3 = joblib.load(f'object_store_v{version}.joblib')
>>> checkFoo(f3)
'0.0.2'
```

### References

- Docs: [`joblib.dump`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.dump.html)
- Docs: [`joblib.load`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.load.html#joblib.load)
- Docs: [Dump and load the dataset without compression](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/compressors_comparison.html#dump-and-load-the-dataset-without-compression)

Comment: @Ahmed Since, it seems that your requirement was solved using the other answer, I am not posting the hack I talked about using `pytorch.nn.Module`. However, there is another simpler alternative that could work for you right out of the box: using `joblib` library. I hope this helps.

Comment: `joblib` is not a serialization library, it's for caching to memory or disk. `joblib`is built on `cloudpickle`, which is similar to `dill`. For completeness, there's a caching package called`klepto` which is built on `dill`, and is similar to `joblib`.  Unfortunately there's not a unified solution.

Comment: @ahmed Thank you, for accepting this answer. Please also consider **voting it up**.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the `dill` author.  You may want to look at the different pickling settings (see `dill.settings`).  For example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   x = 1
...   def bar(self, y):
...     return y + self.x
... 
>>> import dill
>>> f = Foo()
>>> s = dill.dumps(f)
>>> f.bar(5)
6
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   x = 10
...   def bar(self, y):
...     return y + self.x**2
... 
>>> g = dill.loads(s)
>>> g.bar(5)
105
>>> g = dill.loads(s, ignore=True)
>>> g.bar(5)
6
>>> dill.settings
{'protocol': 4, 'byref': False, 'fmode': 0, 'recurse': False, 'ignore': False}
>>>
```

here, `ignore=True` on load tells `dill` to ignore an existing class definition if a newer one exists.  The other settings are to be used on `dump`/`dumps`, where for example, `byref=True` tells `dill` to not store the class definition at all -- just use whatever references is available in the unpicking environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeMcKerns ,  it solved my problem